# Button onclick not working with my second fragment android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am writing a code for a calculator, have two fragment fragmenOne and fragmentTwo respectively. FragmentOne is my default fragment which contains basic function like add, subtract and numbers .The second fragment fragmentTwo contains advance function like sin tan cos...etc.The buttons in my second fragment don't work and don't append the Editbox . But the buttons in my fragmentOne works fine. If I go to fragmentTwo frist and then go to fragmentOne the buttons don't work in fragmentOne also. Please enligthen on this particular issue .The code and the image are provided below.

[image: fragmentOne]

[image: fragmentTwo]

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fragmentstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import de.congrace.exp4j.Calculable;
import de.congrace.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder;
import de.congrace.exp4j.UnknownFunctionException;
import de.congrace.exp4j.UnparsableExpressionException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, add,
sub, mul, div, equal, decimal, cancel, sin, cos, tan, open_bracket, close_bracket;
EditText disp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
    zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
    div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
    equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
    decimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decimal);

    sin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sin);
    cos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cos);
    tan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tan);
    open_bracket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_bracket);
    close_bracket = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close_bracket);

    disp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display_panel);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel); 
    try {
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);
        zero.setOnClickListener(this);

        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        sub.setOnClickListener(this);
        mul.setOnClickListener(this);
        div.setOnClickListener(this);
        equal.setOnClickListener(this);
        decimal.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        sin.setOnClickListener(this);
        cos.setOnClickListener(this);
        tan.setOnClickListener(this);
        open_bracket.setOnClickListener(this);
        close_bracket.setOnClickListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void selectFrag(View view) {
    Fragment fr;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
        fr = new FragmentTwo();

    } else {
        fr = new FragmentOne();

    }

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Editable str = disp.getText();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.zero:
        str = str.append(zero.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.one:
        str = str.append(one.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.two:
        str = str.append(two.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.three:
        str = str.append(three.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.four:
        str = str.append(four.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.five:
        str = str.append(five.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.six:
        str = str.append(six.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.seven:
        str = str.append(seven.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.eight:
        str = str.append(eight.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.nine:
        str = str.append(nine.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.add:
        str = str.append(add.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.sub:
        str = str.append(sub.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.mul:
        str = str.append(mul.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.div:
        str = str.append(div.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.decimal:
        str = str.append(decimal.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.sin:
        str = str.append(sin.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.cos:
        str = str.append(cos.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.tan:
        str = str.append(tan.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;  
    case R.id.open_bracket:
        str = str.append(open_bracket.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;
    case R.id.close_bracket:
        str = str.append(close_bracket.getText());
        disp.setText(str);
        break;  
    case R.id.cancel:
        disp.setText("");
        disp.setHint("Perform Operation");
        break;  
    case R.id.equal:
        String val;
        val = disp.getText().toString();
        Calculable calc = null;
        try {
            Calculable result = new ExpressionBuilder(val).build();
            disp.setText(Double.toString(result.calculate()));
            /* size_num = result.calculate(); */
        } catch (UnknownFunctionException e) {
            disp.setText("ERROR");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnparsableExpressionException e) {
            disp.setText("ERROR");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

}

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/display_panel"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/dispHint"/> 
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="selectFrag"
    android:paddingRight="45dp"
    android:text="@string/basic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="selectFrag"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:text="@string/adv" />

</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff00"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/sin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sin" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/cos"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sin"
     android:text="@string/cos" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/tan"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cos"
     android:text="@string/tan" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/log"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/In"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/In"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/In"
     android:text="@string/log" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/not"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/log"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/log"
     android:text="@string/not" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/close_bracket"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/open_bracket"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/open_bracket"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/open_bracket"
     android:text="@string/close_bracket" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/open_bracket"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/squareroot"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squareroot"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/not"
     android:text="@string/open_bracket" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/In"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/sin"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cos"
     android:text="@string/In" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/squareroot"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/log"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/open_bracket"
     android:text="@string/squareroot" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00ffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/seven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/seven" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eight"
    android:text="@string/nine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/div"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nine"
    android:text="@string/div" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/eight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/four"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seven"
    android:text="@string/eight" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/four"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/four"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/four"
    android:text="@string/five" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/five"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/five"
    android:text="@string/six" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mul"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/six"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/six"
    android:text="@string/mul" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/one"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one"
    android:text="@string/two" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/six"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/two"
    android:text="@string/three" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/three"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/three"
    android:text="@string/sub" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/decimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/one"
    android:text="@string/decimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/decimal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/decimal"
    android:text="@string/zero" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/equal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/two"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/two"
    android:text="@string/equal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/equal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/equal"
    android:text="@string/add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/five"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/five"
    android:text="@string/one" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seven"
    android:text="@string/four" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/div"
    android:text="@string/cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentTwo.java

```
package com.example.fragmentstest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Inflate the layout for this fragment

  return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
 }
}
```

The FragmentOne.java code is same as FragmentTwo.java except the class name is FragmentOne and in 'R.layout.fragment_one' .

Answer (score 1):

When your Activity is created, and the activity_main.xml is inflated, it will only contain the view that are in fragment_one.xml. The views of fragment_two.xml will not be present at the time(Since that Fragment will be added dynamically in runtime). Which means that findViewById(R.id.sin) will return null in the onCreate function, and there's now view to register the onClickListener. That's the reason why there's a need for a try catch block when registering the ClickListeners(to avoid the NullPointerExceptions).

You should register the onClickListeners in the Fragments class, not the Activity. Try removing the setOnClickListener calls from the Activity class, and do that in the activities.

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment    
  View view = inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
  Button sin =  (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sin);
  sin.setOnClickListener(...);
  //other onItemListeners go here
  return view;
 }
}
```

You can reach your MainActivity from the Fragment classes by calling getActivity, and cast it to MainActivity

```
((MainActivity)getActivity())
```

Comment: Can you expand what does ... in the setOnclickListenser contain and how to reach MainActivity from the Fragment classes by calliing getActivity . I mean what should be written on Main Activity..@Balazs

Comment: You should set your View.OnClickListener implementation there. Currently that's your MainActivity. So sin.setOnClickListener(((MainActivity)getActivity())) should work. This means that you register an OnClickListener in your Fragment class, that will be handled by the MainActivity.

The other solution would be to implement OnClickListener in your Fragment classes:

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener

and then you set the clickListener with sin.setOnClickListener(this); in your Fragment class. In this case your Fragment class will handle the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Ashoka try this code this ll help you.Here i am sharing main Activity,fragment one,fragment two class code,Basically we are using buttons in our fragments so it would be better to handle events in fragments and for updation of your edittext use handler in your main activity like this.

Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
EditText disp;
static Handler mHandler;
String str ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    disp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display_panel);
    str = disp.getText().toString();


    mHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
        {

            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what == 1)
            {
                str = str + "seven";
            }
            else 
            {
                str = str + "sin";
            }
            disp.setText(str);

        }
    };
}

public void selectFrag(View view) {
    Fragment fr = null;

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2))
        {
            fr = new FragmentTwo();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } 
        else
        {
            fr = new FragmentOne();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }



}
```

}

Fragment one class

```
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    Button seven = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.seven);
    seven.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Message msgtab=MainActivity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msgtab.what= 1;
            MainActivity.mHandler.sendMessage(msgtab);

        }
    });


  return v;
```

and fragment two class

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    Button sin = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.sin);
    sin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Message msgtab=MainActivity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msgtab.what=2;
            MainActivity.mHandler.sendMessage(msgtab);

        }
    });
    return v;
```